# How does Apple pay for iAds in Apps?

Tags: iphone, iad

So i have an app thats about to be submitted with an iAd banner in it. Just wondering what this means in terms of fee's (for me) and revenue.

Im assuming Apple tracks this info and adds it to my account accordingly.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [the App Stores proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of April 1st, 2012, Apple gives you 70% of earned revenue based on clicks and impressions.

They seem to process that data monthly just like app sales, so you'll receive revenue from June sometime in late July, revenue for July sometime in late August, etc.